¿Donde agregar el enlace de la API en C# o como ocultar el enlace de la API en C#?
He terminado un programa usando Forms y c#, pero me estoy cuestionando que pasa si obtienen el código del programa con las varias herramientas que existe, y usan el en enlace de la API en PHP que está en el hosting, aunque es más porque quisiera dejar el proyecto lo mejor hecho posible. Aquí está el enlace para una solicitud GET, pero para las demás solicitudes tengo el enlace de la misma manera visible en el código

       public async Task SolicitudGet(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage respuesta = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/pagina.php/");

                if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string respuestaJson = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(respuestaJson);

                    var total1= jArray.Where(x => (string)x["X"] == "VALOR" && (string)x["X"] == "VALOR").ToList();
                    var total2= jArray.Where(x => (string)x["X"] == "VALOR" && (string)x["X"] == "VALOR").ToList();
                    var total3= jArray.Where(x => (string)x["X"] == "VALOR" && (string)x["X"] == "VALOR").ToList();
                }
           }
        }

Busqué en internet como ocultarlo o donde se recomienda dejar los enlaces, pero no encontré mucha referencia al respecto, y la que hay es todo de la WEB, encontré sobre el uso de variables de entorno, pero supongo que cuando se compile se guarda y por lo tanto ahí sigue, si conocen de una documentación de como se hace esto y me dejan el enlace les agradecería, no me cansa leer y con mayor gusto si obtendré la solución del último problema de mi proyecto.
Gracias.

es totalmente innecesario... se puede decompilar y obtener? si.. si lo encriptas, en algun momento lo vas a desencriptar, y entonces va a estar plano y se puede obtener... pero lo mas importante.. con cualquier sniffer de red ves las peticiones enviadas... si es tu api, tal vez deberias dar claves unicas a cada usuario para que puedan acceder.. pero igual, cualquiera las podria obtener...

@gbianchi Hola, muchas gracias por responder, si tienes razón, pero cuál sería la buena practica entonces? estoy viendo guardarlo en la configuración de la aplicación usando atributos especiales SpecialSettingAttribute  pero apenas ando investigando porque en la documentación no hay muchos detalles como como usar estos atributos especiales, también tienes razón es una api mía que hace consultas, registros, y las demás solicitudes a una base de datos por lo que pienso que pasa si alguien hace una solicitud POST o GET y obtiene todo. no tengo experiencia con APIS lo siento por la pregunta.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

SOLUCIÓN
Esta es para mí la mejor solución, dado que la aplicación será distribuida con licencia
Entonces, se me ocurrió en cada solicitud enviar en la url o el JSON dependiendo de si es GET o POST la licencia, dejaré aquí el ejemplo para un caso de GET porque es la que desarrolle esta validación
    //En el parámetro $id recibo esta estructura 'usuario_licencia' 
    //el guion bajo '_' es para separar los valores, obtenerlos y usarlos
        function consultaGET($conexion,$id)
    {
        
            $json = $id;
    //Aquí se separo en la primer coincidencia del '_' desde la última posición //hacia atrás entonces aquí obtengo el 'usuario'
            $usuario= substr($json, 0,strrpos($json,'_'));
    //Aquí es donde obtengo la licencia, dado que mide 15 caracteres es lo que
    //resto a la cadena para solo obtener este valor que me interesa
            $lalicencia= substr($json, -15);
        
    //Aquí es donde valido que la licencia sea valida y de esta forma en el código
    //C# no podrán conocer la api para obtener las licencias
            $sqlLicencia = "SELECT * FROM tabla_demislicencias WHERE el_id_de_la_licencia ='$lalicencia'";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($sqlLicencia);
        
            if($resultado)
           {
                $datos = array();
                while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                    $datos[]=$fila;
                }
//Aquí si no es valida la licencia entonces no se devuelve nada
                if($datos==null){
                    // echo "Operación fallida";
                    return;
                }
            }
            
            $sql="SELECT * FROM misclientes WHERE elusuario ='$usuario'";
            $conexion->query($sql);    
        }

con esto mantengo oculto mis tablas importantes y también de cierta manera valido que quien use si o si debe tener una licencia
Para las demás solicitudes es similar, incluso más fácil, por el ejemplo con el POST mandas los datos directamente en el JSON sin problema.
Recalco que esta es la mejor solución para mi caso, porque en la lógica de mi código hago también diversas validaciones, entonces, esto complementa bien, pero puede servirle a quien quiera mantener ocultas sus tablas de llaves o licencias y quizá mejorarlo para su uso.
Gracias.

No entiendo tu respuesta. Preguntas por ocultar una url en C#, pero te autorespondes en PHP, con un código que no hace los que has preguntado

@Yussef Hola, si, mi solución fue con base al comentario de gbianchi que explica que no es posible ocultar el enlace por las diversas maneras en las que uno puede obtenerla, así que cambié el código API en PHP, también mencioné que esta fue la solución que fue mejor para mí, pero ojala le sirva alguien más que busque ocultar alguna tabla en especifico o hacer una validación con licencias o claves. Pero si hay forma de esconder los enlaces también me interesa para mas seguridad. Muchas gracias.
